# Javascript library for table rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I need to show an array of objects in the table like representation. Table has columns with the properties, and when clicked on the column it should show more data inside the table. It should be sortable.

Is there a JS library that could do this, so I dont have to write this from scratch?

Please see the attached image with the JSON object.
When the user clicks on Ana, additional row is inserted.

[image]

Comment: It seems that jqGrid 4.9.1. is capable of doing what I need. But I cant find any examples of its usage.

Comment: Is there an example how to use subgrids?

Comment: Do you used jqGrid before? Which `datatype` you and to use: `"local"` or `"json"`? The difference: should jqGrid make Ajax call to get the data from the server or you do this yourself? In case of `datatype: "local"` the input data come from `data` input parameter which is array of items in the format which you included. In case of `datatype: "json"` the input is `url`. I can post more details after you answer the question about the `datatype`.

Comment: Thank you Oleg for answering and for the great library!!!. I am getting data in JSON myself and feeding it to the Grid. It is very intuitive to use, and within several hours of looking the examples, I do have a Alpha version already. Though, I have two things. How do I set the column width to Auto? 

Another thing is: I have a subgrid. I understand how it works, however... is there an example that shows how to insert the table? I am mainly intersted in HTML.

Comment: Yes. I almost forgot. Is there a way to make data sortable even inside the subgrid? Maybe somehow instantiate another jqGRID and inject it?

Comment: You are welcome! Everything above is possible. It's important that *opened* subgrids will be distorted on sorting of the main grid by default and the user will have to click on "subgrid openiong" icon after sorting. I'll create a small demo for you and will post my answer soon. The only thing, which seems a little strange: the input data have no native id element, which could be good it you would implement editing of data later. Moreover the subgrid from your example will have always one row of data because `loc` id object and not array of objects.

Comment: I am looking forward :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/kc2537ty/1/ which demonstrates the usage of free jqGrid with subgrids. It displays the results like

[image]

after the user clicks on the "+" icon in the second line.

The corresponding code you can find below

```
var mydata = [
        { id: 10, name: "John", lname: "Smith", age: 31, loc: { location: "North America", city: "Seattle", country: "US" } },
        { id: 20, name: "Ana", lname: "Maria", age: 43, loc: { location: "Europe", city: "London", country: "UK" } }
    ];
$("#grid").jqGrid({
    data: mydata,
    colModel: [
        { name: "name", label: "Name" },
        { name: "lname", label: "Last name" },
        { name: "age", label: "Age", template: "integer", align: "center" }
    ],
    cmTemplate: { align: "center", width: 150 },
    sortname: "age",
    iconSet: "fontAwesome",
    subGrid: true,
    subGridRowExpanded: function (subgridDivId, rowid) {
        var $subgrid = $("<table id='" + subgridDivId + "_t'></table>"),
            subgridData = [$(this).jqGrid("getLocalRow", rowid).loc];

        $("#" + subgridDivId).append($subgrid);
        $subgrid.jqGrid({
            idPrefix: rowid + "_",
            data: subgridData,
            colModel: [
                { name: "location", label: "Localtion" },
                { name: "city", label: "City" },
                { name: "country", label: "Country" }
            ],
            cmTemplate: { align: "center" },
            iconSet: "fontAwesome",
            autowidth: true
        });
    }
});
```

Small comments to the code. Free jqGrid saves **all** properties of input data in `data` parameter. I added `id` property to every item of input data. It's not mandatory, but it could be helpful if you would add more functionality to the grid. See [the introduction](http://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html) for more details.

The columns are sortable based on the type of the data specified by `sorttype` property of `colModel`. To simplify usage some standard types of data free jqGrid provides some standard templates which are shortcurts for some set of settings. I used `template: "integer"` in the demo, but you could replace it to `sorttype: "integer"` if only sorting by integer functionality is important.

If the user click on "+" icon to expand the subgrid then jqGrid inserts new row and creates the div for the data part of the subgrid. You can replace `subGridRowExpanded` from above example to the following

```
subGridRowExpanded: function (subgridDivId) {
    $("#" + subgridDivId).html("<em>simple subgrid data</em>");
}
```

to understand what I mean. The unique id of the div will be the first parameter of the callback. One can create any common HTML content in the subgrid. Thus one can create empty `<table>`, append it to the subgrid div and 
then convert the table to the subgrid.

To access to the item of data, which corresponds to the expanding row one can use `$(this).jqGrid("getLocalRow", rowid)`. The return data is the item of original data. It has `loc` property which we need. To be able to use the data as input for jqGrid we create array with the element. I's mostly all, what one have to know to understand how the above code works.

You can add call of `.jqGrid("filterToolbar")` to be able to filter the data or to add `pager: true` (or `toppager: true`, or both) to have the pager and to use `rowNum: 5` to specify the number of rows in the page. In the way you can load relatively large set of data in the grid and the user can use local paging, sorting and filtering. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-4000-20-free-jqgrid.htm) which shows the performance of loading, sorting and filtering of the local grid with 4000 rows and [another one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-40000-20-free-jqgrid.htm) with 40000 rows. All works pretty quickly if one uses local paging and not displays all the data at once.

Comment: Thats awesome explanation and answer. I bow to you.

Answer (score 0):

I use [datatables.net](http://datatables.net) for all my "more complex than lists"-tables. I It's a very well kept library with loads of features and great flexibility. 
In the "con" column I would say that it's so complex that it probably has quite a steep learning curve. Although the documentation is great so there is always hope for most problems.